# What does the "proportional symbol" (∝) mean when used as a time unit prefix?

Tags: triac, time, units

In several datasheets for electronic components, I have seen a ∝ symbol used as a prefix for a time unit, usually seconds, writing as ∝s. As far as I know ∝ is not a valid SI prefix, so what does it mean?  What unit is ∝s?

Comparing different datasheets, I assume it should be rather equivalent to micro prefix, but I'm really not sure.

You can see this use for example in the [BT136 datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/16751/PHILIPS/BT136.html) describing "Gate controlled turn-on time" and defining unit as ∝s.

Comment: Shows up perfectly fine here as µs (Safari, macOS), even with the embedded viewer on that site, or by downloading the PDF and opening it in Preview.

Comment: You just have a problem with your PDF reader, and this is not about electronics.

Comment: The PDF also shows fine with μs on Firefox/Linux. Sounds like a Microsoft fail (though I doubt it's an issue in up-to-date versions of Windows and browsers). Really, character encodings should be a non-issue nowadays... http://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: Irrespective of the root cause, I think it's useful that this has been brought to the community's attention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is most likely an encoding error in the PDF file.  It is simply the wrong symbol.

Here's a section of the BT136 datasheet showing the dynamic characteristics:

[image]

It shows ∝s for several things, among them \$dV_{com}/dt\$.

Figure 12 also refers to \$dV_{com}/dt\$, but it uses units of microseconds (us.)

[image]

Figure 12 uses the common (also incorrect) convention of using a lower case "u" for micro rather than the correct µ symbol.  The dynamic characteristics table probably had the correct symbol in whatever program was used to write the datasheet, but it got mangled in the conversion to PDF.

Comment: The PDF is fine; your viewer is what's broken.

Comment: @Ben-Voight Did you notice that the original post links to an HTML document?

Comment: @david, did _you_ notice that the HTML document has embedded PDF content?

Answer (score 44):

In the common [ISO 8859-1 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), µ is encoded as 0xB5.

In the Windows [Symbol typeface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_(typeface)), ∝ is encoded as 0xB5.

The Symbol font has been commonly used for Greek letters; µ is the only Greek letter that is available elsewhere. This appears to be a common mistake.

Comment: That's a common issue with Ω (Greek capital omega) for Ohm, with so many documents and datasheets showing a W instead - generating confusion, sometimes. Then it's far better IMHO using the lowercase `u`, even though improperly used

Comment: I downloaded the datasheet as a PDF (rather than viewing in the Alldatasheet.com viewer) and the symbol renders correctly.  (Most likely the font is embedded in the PDF.)

Comment: The issue (∝ shows where µ should) occurs independently of browser and OS: it's specific to using the obsolete PDF viewer (pdfjsview) at https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/pdfjsview/web/viewer.html (which is used or not depending on browser). The issue occurs neither in the [pure html version](https://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/16751/PHILIPS/BT136/244/1/BT136.html), nor if [the pdf itself](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/download/16751/PHILIPS/BT136.html) is viewed, or downloaded and viewed.